# Could we get a share on Google+ Icon

Tags: feature-request

At the moment the two we have are Facebook and Twitter and I would like to see a third added into the mix of Google+

I can't speak for everyone but I certainly have far more tech contacts on my G+ then I do on Facebook and other webmasters I have chatted to seem to run the same sort of set up (with Twitter and G+ being more techie than Facebook).

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/any-plans-supporting-google-for-link-sharing-in-the-near-future

Comment: Closing with alternate close reason (cannot close as duplicate of another site's question).